Selecting External Clock Source for NUCLEO-WB55RG Board


I am not finding the clock frequency of the oscillator used on the NUCLEO-WB55RG board?
What's the value?
Where can I find it?

How to select it as clock source for the MCU?
Which one should be selected in the "PLL Source Mux", and "System Clock Mux"?



The frequency will likely be printed directly on the crystal or oscillator on the board or included in the schematic and/or data sheet.  That is not an on-topic question for this site and more appropriate to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, although not as a RTFM question.  Then you cut-off the important part of the clock tree, being wha the HSE is linked to.

You could try reading the User Manual, which tells you what the HSE crystal is. From section 7.7:


HSE: high quality 32 MHz external oscillator with trimming, needed by the RF subsystem


You could also select the Nucleo-WB55 as your target board when creating your project. This will pre-populate the HSE frequency with the correct value:

And to select this as your system clock source, just select it in the System Clock Mux:

This is the default if you created a project specifically for the Nucleo board.

Most of this question is off topic or a matter of reading the documentation.  However the part that is perhaps relevant to SO is:

Which one should be selected in the "PLL Source Mux", and "System Clock Mux"?

The answer depends on how fast you want to run the processor.  The only reason you might not use the PLL is to achieve very low power operation perhaps.  The PLL is a clock multiplier and will generate a clock up to 100MHz from the HSE input.
